# Awk: gsub("\\\\", "\\\\") yields suprising results

Tags: awk, escaping, gsub

Consider the following input:

```
$ cat a
d:\

$ cat a.awk
{ sub("\\", "\\\\"); print $0 }

$ cat a_double.awk
{ sub("\\\\", "\\\\"); print $0 }
```

Now running `cat a | awk -f a.awk` gives

```
d:\
```

and running `cat a | awk -f a_double.awk` gives

```
d:\\
```

and I expect exactly the other way around. How should I interpret this?

```
$ awk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its expected behavior of `awk`. When you run `sub("\\", "\\\\")` in your first script, in `sub`'s inside `"`(double quotes) since we are NOT using `/` for matching pattern we need to escape first `\`(actual literal character) then for escaping we are using `\` so we need to escape that also, hence it will become `\\\\`

```
\\                                          \\
|                                            |
|                                            |
first 2 chars are denoting escaping         next 2 chars are denoting actual literal character \
```

Which is NOT happening your 1st case hence NO match so no substitution in it, in your 2nd awk script you are doing this(escaping part in regex matching section of `sub`) hence its matching `\` perfectly.

---

Let's see this by example and try putting `...` for checking purposes.

***When Nothing happens:*** Since no match on

```
awk '{sub("\\", "....\\\\"); print $0}' Input_file
d:\
```

***When pattern matching happens:***

```
awk '{sub("\\\\", "...\\\\"); print $0}' Input_file
d:...\\
```

***From `man awk`:***

```
gsub(r, s [, t])
For each substring matching the regular expression r in the string t,
 substitute the string s, and return the  number  of  substitutions.
```

---

***How could we could do perform actual escaping part(where we need to use only `\` before character only once)?*** Do mention your regexp in `/../` in first section of `sub` like and we need NOT to double escape `\` here.

```
awk '{sub(/\\/,"&\\")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: what I find counterintuitive: in `gsub("\\\\", "\\\\", $0)` : it seems it replaces 1 \ by 2 \, but each search & replace string is the same ! why is it seen as "1 \" in the left-hand one, and "2\" in the right-hand one? it is as if, internally, it is interpreting the first one twice (and not the second one, probably because it is only used once at the very end at the time to create the replacement string?). Edit: the 2nd answer, by Ed Morton, explains that indeed it is interpreting the left-hand string twice : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64902387/1841533

Answer (score 2):

The first arg to `*sub()` is a regexp, not a string, so you should use regexp (`/.../`) rather than string (`"..."`) delimiters. The former is a literal regexp which is used as-is while the latter defines a dynamic (or computed) regexp which forces awk to interpret the string twice, the first time to convert the string to a regexp and the second to use it as a regexp, hence double the backslashes needed for escaping. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps.

In the following we just need to escape the backslash once because we're using a literal, rather than dynamic, regexp:

```
$ cat a
d:\

$ awk '{sub(/\\/,"\\\\")}1' a
d:\\
```

Your first script would rightfully produce a syntax error in a more recent version of gawk (5.1.0) since `"\\"` in a dynamic regexp is equivalent to `/\/` in a literal one and in that expression the backslash is escaping the final forward slash which means there is no final delimiter:

```
$ cat a.awk
{ sub("\\", "\\\\"); print $0 }

$ awk -f a.awk a
awk: a.awk:1: (FILENAME=a FNR=1) fatal: invalid regexp: Trailing backslash: /\/
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it interprets twice the regex when given as a string!